# Display file page by page

Tags: c, file, file-handling

What I want to do is read a file whose data is much more than the screen size and display it part by part on page by page based on user response.

```
fp = fopen(empRecord.dat,"rb"); // read mode

if( fp == NULL )
{
  perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("The contents of %s file are :\n",empRecord.dat);

while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
  printf("%c",ch);

fclose(fp);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to find out what others did: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while using fgetc which returns an int you should set a self limit on the no of characters read.

```
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
    printf("%c",ch);
```

whatever limit you take like some 100 chars for one page.

```
 int i=0;
 while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
 {
    i++;
    printf("%c",ch);
    if(i==100)
    {
    printf("you want to see more...(1/0)");
    scanf("%d",choice);
    if(choice!=1)
        break;
    else
    clrscr();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you think this would work as lines?
   if(ch=='\n')
{
count++;
if(count%100==0)

Comment: ch=='\n' would certainly work for checking for lines in the file you are reading.

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like homework, so here are some thoughts to guide you (without outright giving you the solution):

- how will you know when you've displayed a screen of data?
- (hint: how will you know when you've displayed a line of data?)
- how will the user indicate that they're ready for the next page?

Often problems answer themselves if you ask the right questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pick number of lines to be printed on your screen at once. Here I am picking 50 lines on screen at once then the display waits for a input from the user.

```
int cnt =0;
while( (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp) ) != NULL )
{
  printf("%s",buf);
  if(cnt == 50)
  {
     getchar();
     cnt =0;
  }
  cnt ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand a bit on [Peter Schneider's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590938/display-file-page-by-page#comment-43606568).  Don't re-invent the wheel.  Your users will be happier with a solution (and hence an interface) they already know how to configure and use from other programs.  The UNIX way of doing things is doing one thing and doing it well.  A program that does displaying pages of output well is called a *pager*.  There used to be [more](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/more1.html) but nowadays [less](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/less1.html) is a superior alternative.

A pager will receive the stuff to display via its standard input stream and then present it to the user in whatever fancy way.  You should leave the choice of the pager program to the user.  A good way of doing this is checking the environment variable `PAGER` for a command to execute as a pager.  If you are doing this, be aware that the environment cannot always be trusted.  If your program is `stuid()`ed, it would be a really bad idea to execute code from an environment variable so you'd better ignore it in that case.  Some people like to provide a more special `MYPROGRAM_PAGER` variable and only if that is not set check for the more general `PAGER` variable.

Another thing you should check for is whether standard output [`isatty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty).  If it is not, simply dump out all the output at once.  Since it will be redirected to a file, neither will it overflow the screen (so a pager will do no good) nor will the user be willing or even able to hit enter (so a pager would actually do bad).

The resulting C program should look fairly simple.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
produce_output(FILE *const stream, const unsigned lines);

int
main(const int argc, const char *const *const argv)
{
  unsigned lines;
  if (argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "error: wrong number of arguments\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  else
    {
      char * endptr;
      long val = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 0);
      if (*endptr != '\0' || val < 0)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "error: not a non-negative integer: %s\n", argv[1]);
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      lines = val;
    }
  if (isatty(fileno(stdin)) && isatty(fileno(stdout)))
    {
      const char * pager_command = NULL;
      FILE * pager_pipe = NULL;
      const char *const env_vars[] = {"MYPROG_PAGER", "PAGER", NULL};
      unsigned i;
      for (i = 0; env_vars[i] != NULL; ++i)
        {
          if ((pager_command = secure_getenv(env_vars[i])) != NULL)
            break;
        }
      if (pager_command == NULL)
        pager_command = "less -XRF";  /* sane default */
      pager_pipe = popen(pager_command, "w");
      if (pager_pipe == NULL)
        {
          fprintf(stderr,
                  "error: popen(\"%s\", \"w\"): %s\n",
                  pager_command, strerror(errno));
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      /* Write everything to the pager at once. */
      if (produce_output(pager_pipe, lines) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: I/O error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      if (pclose(pager_pipe) < 0)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "error: pclose(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
  else
    {
      /* Write everything to stdout at once. */
      if (produce_output(stdout, lines) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: I/O error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int
produce_output(FILE *const stream, const unsigned lines)
{
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 1; i <= lines; ++i)
    {
      const char * suffix;
      switch(i)
        {
        case 1:  suffix = "st"; break;
        case 2:  suffix = "nd"; break;
        case 3:  suffix = "rd"; break;
        default: suffix = "th"; break;
        }
      if (fprintf(stream, "This is the %d%s line of output.\n", i, suffix) < 0)
        return -1;
    }
  if (fflush(stream) < 0)
    return -1;
  return lines;
}
```

[`secure_getenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) is a GNU extension for `getenv` that encapsulates the check whether the environment can be trusted for you.

If you want to make your program more robust, you could implement your own trivial pager and use it as a fallback if the external tool is not available.  In the above example, I simply fall back to a hard-coded default.

To test your program, consider the following cases.

```bash
./myprog 10                                      # short amount of output
./myprog 1000                                    # large amount of output
PAGER='less -M' ./myprog 100                     # use 'less -M' as pager
MYPROG_PAGER='cat' ./myprog 100                  # use 'cat' as a "pager"
MYPROG_PAGER='cat' PAGER='less -M' ./myprog 100  # use 'cat' as a "pager"
./myprog 100 | cat                               # output is not at TTY
./myprog 100 > /dev/full                         # output is a bad file
sudo chown root:root myprog
sudo chmod u+s myprog
./myprog 100                                     # use default pager
PAGER='silly' ./myprog 100                       # must ignore 'silly' in setuid'ed program
```

I'm spending quite some detail on this question because what annoys me by far the most is if programs interact poorly with the user.  Unfortunately, many programming tutorials start out with terrible examples on user interaction, probably because the authors never actually use command line tools themselves.  A consistent good user experience across many (if not all) command line tools is what I consider the most important aspect of a usable computer.